# Move doors in unity3d, at specific points through script C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: sample pic of my desire solution]

I have two doors in my game. Initially they are closed. After that they open and will stop at specific points (pic attached as a sample). So far I have written a script, which rotates the door continuously. I want to stop them, like at 45 angle, need kind suggestion.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string rotate_along = "y";
    public float speed = 10.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
                if (rotate_along == "y") {
                        this.transform.Rotate (0, speed, 0);
                } else if (rotate_along == "x") {
                        this.transform.Rotate (speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                } else if (rotate_along == "z") {
                        this.transform.Rotate (0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
                } else {
                        print ( "please! check your cordinate for rotating for "+gameObject.name );
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use Lerp or Slerp for this:

```
void Update() {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);
}
```

[[Source]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html)

This will move your doors naturally smoothly like in real world and will let you avoid coding horror in vector space. Unity community has pretty much a lot of examples how quaternions works. Here you can find brief explanation of what is difference:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/389713/detaliled-explanation-about-given-vector3slerp-exa.html

Comment: answer accepted, and thanks for better answer, it works fine and smoothly. cheers :-) you guys rocks

Answer (score 1):

You are rotating the doors at a constant velocity without setting a maximum angle..

Something like this should do the trick.. But I haven't been able to test it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string rotate_along = "y";
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    private float _currentAngle = 0.0f;
    private float _targetAngle = 45.0f;
    private float _completed = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (_completed)
            return;

        float angle = speed * Time.deltaTime

        if (_currentAngle + angle > _targetAngle)
        {
            angle = _targetAngle - _currentAngle;
            _completed = true;
        }

        if (rotate_along == "y") 
        {
            this.transform.Rotate (0, angle, 0);
        } 
        else if (rotate_along == "x") 
        {
            this.transform.Rotate (angle, 0, 0);
        } else if (rotate_along == "z") 
        {
            this.transform.Rotate (0, 0, angle);
        } 
        else 
        {
            print ( "please! check your cordinate for rotating for "+gameObject.name );
        }

        _currentAngle += angle;
     }
}
```

Comment: `if (_currentAngle == _targetAngle)` will most likely never be true as it is comparing floats

Comment: You're right, it does leave room for error, although it wouldn't cause a visual problem.. I have updated my answer.